# SpringWebflux. Switch between reactive streams

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I try to create a new record in DB but before I need to fetch another record and take some data from that and set it to a new record. It supposes  `Mono<Subject> subject`  will fill data in `subject.doOnNext(child -> {...})` and after that inserted to DB with `subjectRepository::insert`, but nothing happens and no error, the object is just not inserted.

```
public Mono<Subject> create(Mono<Subject> subject) {
    return subject
            .flatMap(s -> subjectRepository.findById(s.getParentId()))
            .flatMap(parent ->
                    subject.doOnNext(child -> {
                        child.setParentId(parent.getId());
                        child.setCreatedDate(LocalDateTime.now());
                        child.setRoute(Utils.buildRoute(child, parent));
                    }))
            .flatMap(subjectRepository::insert);
}
```

What is my mistake and how to fix it?

Comment: try `flatMap` instead after `subjectRepository.findById(s.getParentId())` so `subjectRepository.findById(s.getParentId()).flatMap(parent -> s.setParentId...))` etc

Comment: Try this snippet.
return subject
        .flatMap(s -> {
         return repository.findById(s.getParentId())
           .flatMap(p-> {
          s.setParentId(p.getId());
                s.setCreatedDate(LocalDateTime.now());
                s.setRoute(Utils.buildRoute(child, parent));
          return repository.save(s);
         });
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subject.doOnNext` is never subscribed, thus is never actually executed. Also, `doOn`*** operators are "side effects" operators and you should not implement business logic or I/O operations within those. You could try something like this:

```java
return subject
    .flatMap(s -> subjectRepository.findById(s.getParentId())
        .map(parent -> {
          s.setParentId(parent.getId());
          s.setCreatedDate(LocalDateTime.now());
          s.setRoute(Utils.buildRoute(child, parent));
          return s;
        }))
    .flatMap(subjectRepository::insert);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet.

```
return subject
    .flatMap(s -> {
        return repository.findById(s.getParentId())
                .flatMap(p-> {
            s.setParentId(p.getId());
            s.setCreatedDate(LocalDateTime.now());
            s.setRoute(Utils.buildRoute(s, p));
            return repository.save(s);
        });
    });
```